# Weak energy condition for a perfect fluid

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

Suppose that we want to impose the weak energy condition for a perfect fluid with four-velocity $$U^a$$

The condition says that for an arbitrary timelike vector $t^a$ we should have:

$$T_{ab}t^{a}t^{b}\geq0$$

Now the question is why the above inequality requires:

$$T_{ab}U^{a}U^{b}\geq0$$

$$AND$$
$$ T_{ab}l^{a}l^{b}\geq0$$

Where $l^a$ is a null vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timelike vector case implies the null vector case by continuity; we can choose timelike vectors such that the limiting case becomes a null vector. To be more precise, since the inequality 
$$
T_{ab}t^at^b \geq 0
$$
must hold for all timelike vectors, in particular it must hold for vectors of the form
$$
t^a(\alpha)= \sqrt{1+\alpha^2}v^a + \alpha s^a,
$$
where we have chosen a timelike unit vector $v^a$ and an orthogonal spacelike unit vector $s^a$ such that an arbitrary null vector $\ell^a = N(v^a + s^a)$. We can of course regard the null vector $\ell^a$ to be independent of $N$, so taking the limit we find
$$
\lim_{\alpha \to \infty}t^a(\alpha)= \lim_{N \to \infty}\ell^a = \ell^a.
$$
So if the inequality does not hold for some null vector we can choose a sufficiently large $\alpha$ that the inequality does not hold for the timelike vector constructed above.

The case $T_{ab}U^aU^b \geq 0$ follows of course from $U^a$ being a timelike vector.